# Compare two atomic ints Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, atomic

In Qt5 a few operations on `QAtomicInt` have disappeared, including the operator==.

Does anyone know how I can compare two QAtomicInts in Qt5? The old code was like this:

```
qAtomicInt a;
qAtomicInt b;
if(a == b)
    //Do something
```

As far as I understand the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html) I could do it like this:

```
qAtomicInt a;
qAtomicInt b;
if(a.load() == b.load())
    //Do something
```

But if I do it like this, is the compare operation still atomic? Can the values that are being compared change while this operation is in progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct taking into account the changes in Qt5. You can use `load()` or `loadAcquire()` for comparison of `QAtomicInt`.

Though these operations itself are marked as atomic while you are comparing ints in

```
if(a.load() == b.load())
```

values in QAtomicInts may change.

Operator== which was available in Qt4

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qatomicint.html#operator-eq-eq

was not marked as atomic in documentation, by the way.

Comment: While an interesting and important information, this answer does not provide a solution.

Comment: So are you saying that while "if(a.load() == b.load()) is not atomic as values might change during comparison, that even in the old code (this allready existed in Qt4 times) it never was atomic to begin with?

Comment: @DrDonut Yes, old code was not atomic and new code is not atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Atomic comparisons are not generally supported. The comparison between atomic integers was not atomic in Qt 4 either. Just because there was an `operator==` didn't mean it was atomic.

Most likely, if your code depends on atomic comparisons, your design is wrong. Atomic variables stand on their own: each is atomic only in isolation from any other one.

If you truly need a pair of integers that can be atomically compared, you need to put all of them into a single atomic variable. E.g. two 16 bit ints fit into a 32 bit atomic int, four 16 bit ints fit into a 64 bit atomic int, etc. The atomic comparison is then a load followed by comparison done on the parts that you've just atomically loaded.

The question has nothing much to do with Qt: it's not any different with std::atomic.

If you need more than lock-free atomics provide, you will be fine protecting the access to the data via a mutex. In uncontested cases, Qt and other well-implemented mutexes use atomics for synchronization, so an uncontested mutex lock costs the same as an atomic compare-and-store.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. In the end it was solved as described in the comments above. I don't know if this non-atomic comparison will give me problems, time will tell :)